# Setting Output Extent (Environment Setting) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I'm trying to figure out how to set my output extent before creating Thiessen Polygons in a loop of ~100 points shapefile. (ArcMap 10.0 - Python)

```
for i in range(3,51,1):
    arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis("AVF%i" % i,"AVF%iVoronoi" % i,"ONLY_FID")
```

Basically I want my extent to be the same for each iteration.

I first found:

```
arcpy.Extent(293490,5898230,316430,5930230)
```

then someone told me about this [ESRI help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/DataFrame/00s300000003000000/):

```
#use 'CURRENT' if running from ArcMap, when published use MXD on disk

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    newExtent = df.extent
    newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = 293490,5898230
    newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = 316430,5930230
    df.extent = newExtent
```

but in any case, when I run my loop, the size of the output is not reflecting the changes.

ps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996965/output-extent-environment-setting/8997122#8997122

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are just creating an [`Extent`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extent/000v0000006r000000/) object with:

```
arcpy.Extent(293490,5898230,316430,5930230)
```

...but not actually setting the `arcpy.env.extent` property (unless you have more code that is not posted in your original question). From the [docs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000):

```
import arcpy

# Set the extent environment using a keyword.
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

# Set the extent environment using the Extent class.
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(-107.0, 38.0, -104.0, 40.0)  # <-- Have you tried this?

# Set the extent environment using a space-delimited string.
arcpy.env.extent = "-107.0 38.0 -104.0 40.0"
```

Try setting it like:

```
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(293490,5898230,316430,5930230)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works perfectly !
`import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/Users/nlec002/Documents/ArcGIS/Voronoi/AVFVoronoi.mxd")

for i in range(3,51,1):
    arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis("C:/Users/nlec002/Documents/ArcGIS/Voronoi/AVF%i.shp" % i,"C:/Users/nlec002/Documents/ArcGIS/Voronoi/AVF%iVoronoi.shp" % i,"ONLY_FID")
    arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(267936,5892195,341661,5940210)`